# Woocommerce attribute term parent/child?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, parent-child

I have some product attributes like so:

-Color (attribute)

--Blue (term)

---sky blue ( term with parent of blue)

--- navy ( term with parent of blue)

-- Red (term)

--- crimson (term with parent of red)

--- pink  (term with parent of red)

In my php I can get the id of a terms parent pretty easy with $term->parent but the next step in what I'm trying to achieve is baffling me. How can I somehow differentiate between the two. I'm not fussy I just need to be able to style them differently so if I am able to get the title/name/slug of the parent instead of just the id or if I can add a css class to the parent or child to separate them or any other suggestion,  I'm open to all. I have spent a fair amount of time searching for explanations on the usage of parent child terms but nothing out there. I've, through trial and error, tried many different code snippets but most would work with a post/category taxonomy but not attribute terms. I think it's because the terms aren't actually s taxonomy but a meta if the attribute. I really hope someone will be able to assist.

EDIT: I realise I should show my research so where I'm at so far.

I can get the parent ID of a term on certain taxonomies like 'product_cat' or 'category' using the following:

```
wp_get_term_taxonomy_parent_id( $term_id, $taxonomy );
```

but this will not return any data when it comes to Attribute terms. There is no documentation on what type of taxonomy an attribute term is.

I can also get the term's parent ID with "$term_id->parent" but don't know of any option to get name/title of term parent.

I've also tried

```
$parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );
$children = get_term_children($term->term_id, get_query_var('taxonomy')); 
   if(($parent->term_id!="" && sizeof($children)>0)) {
         echo ('has parent and child');// 
   }elseif(($parent->term_id!="") && (sizeof($children)==0)) {
         echo ('has parent, no child');// 
   }elseif(($parent->term_id=="") && (sizeof($children)>0)) {
         echo ('no parent, has child');// 
   }
```

That returns the third option (no parent, has child) for all in the list regardless of whether the term has parent or child.

Hope that helps. If anyone can tell me what taxonomy type an attribute term actually is I may be able to solve it.

Comment: (this may be obvious to PHP/WP devs but) after some trial & error I have realised that an attribute term IS a custom taxonomy itself. For anyone else reading this needing help: if you are trying to target $term and need the taxonomy use the custom name of the attribute i.e. if you create a color attribute . use "pa_color" as the taxonomy.

Comment: Still need to figure out how to get the prent term name or title instead of just the ID number.

Comment: So i was never able to solve this. However i switched our methods an by using advanced custom fields plugin I was able to do some great things targeting product attributes and terms. If anyone had any questions about the advice feel free to ask and i might be able to assisst with what i learned.

Comment: I need help! I am also trying to get child attributes. @Websp1nner